# What's the Max character limit for a post in WordPress?

Tags: characters

Very software out there has a limit for character but I haven't seen any such limit for a post in WordPress.
So I need to know if there is actually a Max character limit for a post in WordPress or not? If there is then what's the limit?

Comment: In what context? Per post? Per comment? What? Total database capacity? No offense but as written the question makes very little sense.

Comment: Apologies!! I need to know character limit for Post in WordPress and I have also made changes in the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [database description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts) you'll see that the post content column is `longtext`, which is:

> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 − 1)
> characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
> multibyte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns
> also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the
> client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGTEXT value is
> stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes
> in the value.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

You will more likely run out of usable memory before the max character length becomes an issue.